# Creating a template using *ngFor that gather the information of the form as a whole and not separated pieces of information on angular

Tags: angular, forms, typescript, templates

**I have this code:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm, FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-adm',
    // templateUrl: './adm.component.html',
    template: `<form #f="ngForm" (submit)="form_submit(f)">
        <input ngModel name="nomeEmpresa" placeholder="Nome da empresa" type="text"><br>
        <input ngModel name="atuacao" placeholder="Ramo de atuação" type="text"><br>
        <input ngModel name="vagas" placeholder="Numero de vagas" type="number"><br>
        <input ngModel name="salario" placeholder="Salário" type="number"><br>
        <input ngModel name="descricao" placeholder="Descrição da vaga" type="text" ><br>
        <button type="submit">Lançar vaga</button>
    </form>
    <div>
        <h1 *ngFor="let p of addItem">{{p.Empresa}}</h1>
        <p *ngFor="let p of addItem">{{p.Atuacao}}</p>
        <p *ngFor="let p of addItem">{{p.Vagas}}</p>
        <p *ngFor="let p of addItem">{{p.Salario}}</p>
        <p *ngFor="let p of addItem">{{p.Descricao}}</p>
    </div>
    <app-leitura><app-leitura>
    `,
    styleUrls: ['./adm.component.css']
})
export class FormItemSubmit implements OnInit {
    addItem: Array<any>;
    constructor(){}
    ngOnInit(){
        this.addItem = new Array<any>();
    }
    form_submit(f:NgForm){
        this.addItem.push({
            Empresa: f.form.controls.nomeEmpresa.value,
            Atuacao: f.form.controls.atuacao.value,
            Vagas: f.form.controls.vagas.value,
            Salario: f.form.controls.salario.value,
            Descricao: f.form.controls.descricao.value,
        });
        console.log(this.addItem);
    }
}
```

My intention was that the information on the input was displayed as a group, as my example of output shows:

example1

example1.0

```
1
    1.1

    as a whole
```

(now for the second input, it should be like this)

example2

example2.0

```
2
2.1
as a whole
```

So everytime the button is pressed it creates a new entire form output that is displayed together but instead I am getting this output:

```
example1
example2
example1.0
example2.0

1

2

1.1

2.1

as a whole

as a whole
```

It display as groups, but instead of separating between form inputs it separates by the {{p.something }}.
any solutions?

PS: sorry if I failed to express my question, english is not my first language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to wrap it this way:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let p of addItem">
<h1>
{{p.Empresa}}
</h1>
<p>
{{p.Atuacao}}
</p>
<p>
{{p.Vagas}}
</p>
<p>
{{p.Salario}}
</p>
<p>
{{p.Descricao}}
</p>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked perfectly, I could not imagine it would be so simple.